# How can I turn the rows of a csv file into a list of objects?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

I am working with patient data. I am storing the patient data in a CSV file. Each row is a new patient and there are hundreds of patients. I would like to access patients as incidences of a list. For example, index 0 of a my patients list would output a patient object with attributes like:

{ first: 'Zakariah',
last: 'Siyaji',
age: 21 }

and so on. The following is the code that I was writing although I couldn't see how I could generate many objects without having the initialize each one manually. Considering that there are hundreds of patients, this would be highly impractical.

```
import ASD as asd

class Patient:
    mrn = 0
    first = '' 
    last = '' 
    gender = 0
    smoker = 0
    bmi = 0
    asa = 0 
    cci = 0
    dob = '' 
    dos = '' 
    age = 0

    def setData(self, mrn, first, last, gender, smoker, bmi, asa, cci, dob, dos, age):
        self.mrn = mrn
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.gender = gender
        self.smoker = smoker
        self.bmi = bmi
        self.asa = asa
        self.cci = cci
        self.dob = dob
        self.dos = dos
        self.age = age

    def showData(self):
        print("MRN\t:",self.mrn)
        print("First\t:", self.first)
        print("Last\t:", self.last)
        print("Gender\t:", self.gender)
        print("Smoker\t:", self.smoker)
        print("BMI\t:",self.bmi)
        print("ASA\t:", self.asa)
        print("CCI\t:", self.cci)
        print("DOB\t:", self.dob)
        print("DOS\t:", self.dos)
        print("Age\t:", self.age)

def main():

    p1 = Patient()
    p1.setData(asd.file1['MRN'][0],
               asd.file1['First'][0],
               asd.file1['Last'][0],
               asd.file1['Female'][0],
               asd.file1['Smoker'][0],
               asd.file1['BMI'][0],
               asd.file1['ASA'][0],
               asd.file1['CCI'][0],
               asd.file1['DOB'][0],
               asd.file1['DOS'][0],
               asd.file1['Age'][0])
    p1.showData()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of `ASD` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply import pandas and read your CSV file and access the information of patients.

```
import pandas as pd
patients = pd.read_csv("patients.csv")

# To access information
patients.loc[0] #or patients.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Well I don’t have any issue accessing data, I’m having issues with turning those rows into objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module supports reading from a csv file. If you wish to do complex data interpolation then ofcourse there's pandas. Assuming its a simple operation this should look something like this,

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
  reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
  count == 0
  for row in reader:
    if count != 0 # skip the header, or do something here
    p = Patient(row["mrn"], row["first"], row["last"], row["gender"], row["smoker"], row["bmi"], row["asa"], row["cci"], row["dob"], row["dos"], row["age"])
    print(p)
    count += 1
```

Also I see your patient definition class doesn't follow idiomatic python. It can be rewritten to be more pythonic in the following way.

```
class Patient:
   def __init___(self, mrn=None, first=None, last=None, gender=None, smoker=None, bmi=None, asa=None, cci=None, dob=None, dos=None, age=None)
     self.mrn = mrn
     self.first = first
     self.last = last
     self.gender = gender
     self.smoker = smoker
     self.bmi = bmi
     self.asa = asa
     self.cci = cci
     self.dob = dob
     self.dos = dos
     self.age = age
def __repr__(self):
    return '''MRN: {}
            First: {}
            ...
            ASA: {}'''.format(self.mrn, self.first,....,self.asa)
```

Since your constructor has many fields, one of the biggest advantages is that you can use keyword arguments to instantiate your class and run a lower risk of messing some field with some other value.